# Expected object undefined using Jasmine toEqual

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, jasmine

I've created a service to mask data and written a Jasmine test to compare actual and expected objects.
When I run the test I get undefined on the `actual` object returned from the service. Although when I console log it `console.log(JSON.stringify(maskedData));` the `maskedData` is defined.

```
LOG LOG: '{"handle":"#######@#####.com","displayName":"####ane","iss":"####:###.###.##.#"}'
Expected undefined to equal <jasmine.objectContaining(Object({ handle: '#######@#####.com', displayName: '####ane' }))>.
```

Question:

Why does service return object evaluate to undefined in a test but defined in a console log?

I did think this could be an async bug hence the undefined value during test, but since console logging the value works I don't think so.

This is a gist of the test in question:

```
const mockAddUserAction = {
    type: 'AddUser',
    payload: {
      handle: 'tedjane@five.com',
      displayName: 'tedJane',
      iss: 'http:192.168.12.1',
    },
  };

it('should mask PII user action.payload data with nested properties', async () => {
    const maskedData = service.maskPiiData(mockAddUserAction);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(maskedData));
    expect(maskedData.payload).toEqual(
      jasmine.objectContaining({
        handle: '#######@#####.com',
        displayName: '####ane',
      }),
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `expect` instruction is invoked before the service returns a result. You need to synchronize the asynchronous service call. Try to add `await` to the line where you invoke your service.

```
const maskedData = await service.maskPiiData(mockAddUserAction);
```